# cmd.exe version comparison?

Tags: windows-server-2000, windows-server-2003-r2, windows-command-prompt

When using batch files or console applications on Windows servers the window in question can allow text to be hightlighted (marked) for copying and pasting. Doing this pauses the batch/application and it will only resume after the copy operation.

Or this is what I thought to be true. Recently on a Windows 2003 R2 SP2 server I noted that whilst the scrolling was paused the operations were not. Does anyone know if

1. my description in the 1st para is true for older windows
2. is not true for Windows 2003 R2 SP2
3. when it changed
4. a full version comparison table for cmd.exe across different OS' ?

Thanks for reading

(Windows 2000 tag as that was the OS I used most before 2003 R2)

Answer (score 1):

On every Windows OS I know of (including 2000), selecting text in the `cmd` window will not inherently pause the actual progress of any process or batch file running in that window.

Comment: Yes it will, until the selection is unselected, e.g. by copying. tested WinXP and Win2k